# Addiing corner radius to buttons in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add corner radius to buttons in c# code. When I run, all buttuns disappear.  Any helps or tips are welcome

```
Style s = new Style(typeof(Button));
ControlTemplate control = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Button));
control.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
control.VisualTree.SetValue(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(10));
s.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.TemplateProperty,control));
```

Comment: The recommended way to build ui in code is to use xamlreader.parse (or load). You can then use a string exactly like the XAML you would in a view and easily try that XAML pasted into a test window. Frameworkelementfactory is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a ContentPresenter to your Border:

```
elemFactory.AppendChild(new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof (ContentPresenter)));
```

Comment: Thank you. And what is the eleFactory?

Comment: Thats the FrameworkElementFactory you created for the Border. Without a contentpresenter you wont get any content in your buttons and the border (which is not set to have any visible borders or background in your example) wont get any size and so not be visible at all.